# How do we make sure labels are printing with proper capitalization?

Tags: drupal, address-labels, 4.3

CiviCRM 4.3.8 (upgrading as soon as we can!) Drupal 7.50

We have a situation where, when people fill out the contribution form to make a donation, their name and address information is captured exactly as they type it (such as lack of capitalization or all caps). How to we ensure that when we print address labels, the labels have proper capitalization?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pete suggests two good extensions - I've personally had good luck with [Cividesk Normalize](https://github.com/cividesk/com.cividesk.normalize).

Comment: a new one to me, thx for adding it.

Answer (score 1):

Several options but none out of the box that I know of.

1/ Sign up for a provider that does Address Checking

2/ check out the Extensions that could do this for [First and Last names eg [this](https://civicrm.org/extensions/capitalisation-corrector) or [this](https://civicrm.org/extensions/normalise-data-entered-firstname-last-name)

I think the main problem is that whatever validation rules you can think of, someone will have something that breaks those rules. eg should it be 'de Beer' or 'De Beer' in a street name etc.